# Theorem 6.9 about Riemann integral in PMA Rudin

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

How he uses continuity of $\alpha$ on $[a,b]$? I thought for a moment but any results.
By the way theorem 4.23 is Intermediate value property of continuous function. 
[image]

Can anyone help me to understand this moment of the proof?

Answer (score 10):

Basically, he's saying that for each $i = 1,\dots, n$, we can find $x_i\in[a,b]$ such that
$$ \alpha(x_i) = \alpha(a) + \frac{\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)}{n}i $$
i.e. we can find $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ such that $\{\alpha(x_i)\}_{i=1}^{n}$ are evenly spaced between $\alpha(a)$ and $\alpha(b)$. We can do this because IVT guarantees that we can indeed take on any intermediate value, including those dividing the interval between $\alpha(a)$ and $\alpha(b)$ into evenly spaced intervals.

Comment: But would be if our function $\alpha$ not continuous?

Comment: If $\alpha$ were not continuous, there's no guarantee that we can hit those intermediate values.

Comment: Can you show some example?

Comment: Ok, how about for $[a,b] = [0,1]$, let $\alpha(0) = 0$, $\alpha(1)=1$, and $\alpha(x) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ for $x\in(0,1)$?

Comment: I think that function $\alpha$ must be monotonic.

Comment: @RFZ I've edited the example.

Comment: In this case exists partition of $[a,b]$ such that $a=x_0<x_1<\dots<x_{n-1}<x_n=b$ with $n>2$ such that$\alpha(x_{j+1})-\alpha(x_j)=0$. Is my reasoning right?

Comment: @RFZ There's nothing wrong with you're reasoning, although the point is that in this example we cannot find a partition such that $\Delta\alpha_i = (1-0)/n = 1/n$, since the only possible values of $\Delta\alpha_i$ are $0$, $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$, and $1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

Answer (score 5):

Geometrically, graph $\alpha$, then subdivide the image $[\alpha(a), \alpha(b)]$ into $n$ subintervals of equal length
$$
\Delta \alpha = \frac{\alpha(b) - \alpha(a)}{n}.
$$
Each "break point" $y_{i} = \alpha(a) + i\, \Delta\alpha$ is a value of $\alpha$ by continuity (the intermediate value property), so there exists an $x_{i}$ in $[a, b]$ such that $y_{i} = \alpha(x_{i})$. These $(x_{i})_{i=0}^{n}$ are the desired partition $P$.

**Edit**: The right-hand diagram shows what can happen if $\alpha$ is discontinuous: The graph of $\alpha$ may miss one or more lines $y = y_{i}$, and so fail to determine a partition point.

[image: A discontinuous function may miss specified horizontal lines]

Comment: But would be if our function $\alpha$ not continuous?

Comment: A discontinuous monotone function has jump discontinuities; it could happen that $\alpha$ "misses" one or more values $y_{i}$.